# move command fails from batch file. But runs successfully when executed from command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command, move

I have a simple move command as:

```
move tfa.war ..\..\..\tomcat\webapps
```

When i run this command in command prompt it works fine. But when i put this command in a batch file with variables like so, and execute the batch file in command prompt it fails with the message "The system cannot find the file specified".

```
cmd.exe /C webapp_deploy.bat tfa
```

And the contents of webapp_deploy.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF

set app_name=%~1
set webapps_directory=..\..\..\tomcat\webapps

move %app_name%.war %webapps_directory%
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Always use full path names in batch files. It bypasses all problems like this.

Comment: the reason is: when starting by Task Scheduler, the working folder usually is `%systemroot%\system32`, so `tfa.war` isn't found. Using full path solves it. Tip: get used to enclose paths/filenames in quotes to avoid syntax errors with spaces: `move "C:\full path\to\%appname.war" "%webapps_directory%"